# how to query in linq to sql such way?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to select the user. For this user I am marinating the designation Id which is foreign key in user table. as well as I am maintaining the  ActiveStatus for soft delete. I want to select the user who are active , but instead of designation Id it must show designation name (like Director, Manager ..so on). How to join 2 tables and get result in linq to sql .
I am using ASP.NET + C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a `designation` table with `DesignationId` and `Name`, with the `DesignationId` as a FK to the user table.

```
from user in users
where user.ActiveStatus == "Active" // or whatever
select new {Name = user.Name, DesignationName = user.Designation.Name}
```